# Best practice for Next.js: pathname from useRouter in multiple components or pass as prop?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Let's say I have a Layout that uses a NavMobile and a NavDtop component that show depending on screen size. Both need the current pathname from next/router to disable the link to the current page.

```
const router = useRouter();
const currentPage = router.pathname;
```

Is it better to ask for the current pathname in the Layout and pass it on to the components as props or should each component ask for the pathname on its own?

Answer (score 0):

I guess best practice would be passing it as props, in the future you will only have one source of truth, ie: if you decide to make changes you won't forget to update *both* components.

Imo the performance difference will be thin enough for both solutions to be good. If you already pass a lot of props in your components it won't hurt if each nav ask.